# Android Json Project application crashes

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I am having a little trouble with my android development project. I have created an application which allows the user to insert/read/update and delete records from a MySQL database. This is using JSON. The application keeps crashing with a fatal exception main? Not too sure what it is as none of the pages created are showing any errors. I also have used php to connect to the database and query it. There are 5 java files and 4 xml layout files. Not sure if you would like me to put them all on here as it might get to be too much so for now I will add them in my public folder of dropbox, if I need to put all of the pages here I will edit the question. https://www.dropbox.com/s/iakgmx7aci78b65/AndroidAssignment.zip?dl=0

UPDATE:

I managed to get rid of most errors but its sending a error saying unable to find explicit activity class ViewAllEmployee for the onClick method;

```
Process: com.example.assignment.androidassignment, PID: 2211   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.assignment.androidassignment/com.example.assignment.androidassignment.ViewAllEmployee}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
at com.example.assignment.androidassignment.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:93)
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.assignment.androidassignment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

//Defining views
private EditText editTextLatitude;
private EditText editTextLongitude;
private EditText editTextTimeInserted;

private Button buttonAdd;
private Button buttonView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Initializing views
    editTextLatitude = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLat);
    editTextLongitude = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLon);
    editTextTimeInserted = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTimeInserted);

    buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
    buttonView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonView);

    //Setting listeners to button
    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    //Adding an employee
    private void addEmployee(){

    final String lat = editTextLatitude.getText().toString().trim();
    final String lon = editTextLongitude.getText().toString().trim();
    final String timeInserted = editTextTimeInserted.getText().toString().trim();

    class AddEmployee extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Adding...","Wait...",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... v) {
            HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(Config.KEY_LAT,lat);
            params.put(Config.KEY_LON,lon);
            params.put(Config.KEY_TIMEINSERTED,timeInserted);

            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String res = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.URL_ADD, params);
            return res;
        }
        }

        AddEmployee ae = new AddEmployee();
        ae.execute();
 }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == buttonAdd){
        addEmployee();
    }

    if(v == buttonView){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ViewAllEmployee.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        startActivity(new Intent(this,com.example.assignment.androidassignment.ViewAllEmployee.class));
    }
    } 
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.assignment.androidassignment"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="18"
android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" >

<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

UPDATE: ViewAllEmployee.java

```
package com.example.assignment.assignment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView; 
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class ViewAllEmployee extends Activity implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

private ListView listView;

private String JSON_STRING;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_all_employee);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    getJSON();
}


private void showEmployee() {
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,  String>>();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
            String UserID = jo.getString(Config.TAG_ID);
            String Lat = jo.getString(Config.TAG_LAT);

            HashMap<String, String> employees = new HashMap<>();
            employees.put(Config.TAG_ID, UserID);
            employees.put(Config.TAG_LAT, Lat);
            list.add(employees);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            ViewAllEmployee.this, list, R.layout.list_item,
            new String[]{Config.TAG_ID, Config.TAG_LAT},
            new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name});

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void getJSON() {
    class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(ViewAllEmployee.this, "Fetching Data", "Wait...", false, false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            JSON_STRING = s;
            showEmployee();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String s = rh.sendGetRequest(Config.URL_GET_ALL);
            return s;
        }
    }
    GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
    gj.execute();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewEmployee.class);
    HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap)  parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String UserID = map.get(Config.TAG_ID).toString();
    intent.putExtra(Config.EMP_ID, UserID);
    startActivity(intent);
 }
 }
```

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. What code is crashing? Post it here. What is the stack trace of the error? Post it here. Very few will want to go to your dropbox and download something. Just post the relevant information here using proper formatting and you will be more likely to get some help with this.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, i have updated the question with errors, it seems to be a error in the support library @drschultz

Comment: the error is in the android-support-v7-appcompat, i checked that both the support package and my project have the same min and required sdk and also added the library in my project from properties. I will try it in android studio and let you know how i get along @MrsEd thanks for your response :)

Comment: @MrsEd Please see Update in my question. The application now runs but when i try clicked the 'ViewAllEmployee' button i get a error unable to find explicitly activity class?

Comment: I have rectified the issue, i posted another question, apparently i was nesting <activity> tags in my manifest. I will accept this answer anyway as you did help too. Thank you @MrsEd :)

Comment: @MrsEd http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174298/android-studio-unable-to-find-explicit-activity-class/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the activity `ViewAllEmployee` to your manifest between the `Application` tags

```
<application ...>
    <activity
        android:name=".ViewAllEmployee" />
</application>
```

Comment: That still is not working. I have searched everywhere online and everyone is giving this solution, even after i include in AndroidManifest it still throws the same error :/ Not sure what else it can be? @MrsEd

Comment: Thats ok, i am calling a java class which is called ViewAllEmployee keep a eye on my question, will update now with the code for this class @MrsEd

Comment: Oh right, so how would i call the activity showEmployee in ViewAllEmployee from a my MainActivity class? @MrsEd

Comment: Yeah it was all abit confusing but hey thats how you learn right! @MrsEd