# Android Studio unable to find explicit activity class

Tags: java, android, mysql

i have a application that allows me to alter/add/delete from mysql database. The application opens up fine when i run it but when i try clicking on the 'ViewAllEmployee' button i keep getting a error saying it cannot find explicit activity class. I have looked online and tried all solutions that have worked for people with this problem before. I have added it into my AndroidManifest too but it still doesn't want to work. Can anyone help? Literally been trying to fix this for hours!

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.assignment.androidassignment"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="18"
android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity
    android:name="com.example.assignment.androidassignment.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" >

<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <activity
            android:name="com.example.assignment.androidassignment.ViewAllEmployee"
        />
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java -- Error showing when onClick for 'ViewAllEmployee' is clicked:

```
package com.example.assignment.androidassignment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

//Defining views
private EditText editTextLatitude;
private EditText editTextLongitude;
private EditText editTextTimeInserted;

private Button buttonAdd;
private Button buttonView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Initializing views
    editTextLatitude = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLat);
    editTextLongitude = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLon);
    editTextTimeInserted = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTimeInserted);

    buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
    buttonView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonView);

    //Setting listeners to button
    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonView.setOnClickListener(this);
   }


  //Adding an employee
  private void addEmployee(){

    final String lat = editTextLatitude.getText().toString().trim();
    final String lon = editTextLongitude.getText().toString().trim();
    final String timeInserted = editTextTimeInserted.getText().toString().trim();

    class AddEmployee extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Adding...","Wait...",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... v) {
            HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(Config.KEY_LAT,lat);
            params.put(Config.KEY_LON,lon);
            params.put(Config.KEY_TIMEINSERTED,timeInserted);

            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String res = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.URL_ADD, params);
            return res;
        }
    }

    AddEmployee ae = new AddEmployee();
    ae.execute();
     }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == buttonAdd){
        addEmployee();
    }

    if(v == buttonView){
        startActivity(new Intent(this,com.example.assignment.androidassignment.ViewAllEmployee.class));
    }
  }
 }
```

LogCat errors:

```
12-09 03:34:46.634 2489-2489/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 =Process: com.example.assignment.androidassignment, PID: 2489
 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.assignment.androidassignment/com.example.assignment.androidassignment.ViewAllEmployee}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
 at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
 at com.example.assignment.androidassignment.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:91)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: thats no problem, i do have another question that has also been bugging me for the last few hours, is that ok or are you busy? will post it and tag you in it anyway. If you are busy then not to worry. I appreciate the help you have given so far :) @MrsEd

Comment: yes it will have to be a new post, will tag you shortly.. @MrsEd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from

```
if(v == buttonView){
    startActivity(new Intent(this,com.example.assignment.androidassignment.ViewAllEmployee.class));
}
```

to

```
if(v == buttonView){
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ViewAllEmployee.class));
}
```

from

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.assignment.androidassignment"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="18"
android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity
    android:name="com.example.assignment.androidassignment.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" >

<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <activity
            android:name="com.example.assignment.androidassignment.ViewAllEmployee"
        />
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.assignment.androidassignment"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="18"
android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity
    android:name="com.example.assignment.androidassignment.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" >

<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>


</activity>
 <activity
            android:name="com.example.assignment.androidassignment.ViewAllEmployee"
        />
</application>

</manifest>
```

please change the above and this is happening because of nesting of activity inside manifest

Comment: That worked! Something so simple can drive someone crazy lol. Thank you @Manojkumar :)

Answer (score 2):

You are nesting `<activity>` tags in your Manifest. Take them apart:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.assignment.androidassignment.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
     android:name="com.example.assignment.androidassignment.ViewAllEmployee"/>
```